# Need to remove the admin menu item from a be theme in wordpress

Tags: menus, admin

I need to remove the few admin menus of BeTheme from admin wordpress menu.
Although this code works (when added to functions.php) for usual wordpress admin menus

```
 add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );

  function my_remove_menu_pages() {
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );                   //Posts
    remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );                 //Media
    remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );          //Comments
    remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );                 //Appearance
    remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );                  //Users
    remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                  //Tools
    remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );        //Settings

  };
```

For BeTheme additional pages I can't manage to hide them.
These pages have links:

```
  wp-admin/admin.php?page=betheme
  wp-admin/admin.php?page=be-websites
  wp-admin/admin.php?page=be-status
  wp-admin/admin.php?page=be-support
  wp-admin/admin.php?page=be-changelog
```

I tried with only end names 'betheme' and together with page=betheme but nothing.

How could i remove these menu items from admin wordpress menu?

Comment: have you had a look through the theme files to see where/how they're added? might help in figuring out how to remove them. You also need to make sure that you remove them *after* they're added in case the code to add them runs after yours.

Comment: No mozboz, how do I do that?

Comment: Search in all the .php files in the theme directory for one of those strings from the menu links, e.g. 'be-changelog'.

Comment: Thanks, I have found it in two files. One of them content is:
<?php endif; ?>
   95   <a href="admin.php?page=be-support" class="nav-tab<?php if( $current_screen == 'betheme_page_be-support' ) echo ' nav-tab-active'; ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Manual & Support', 'mfn-opts' ); ?></a>
   96:  <a href="admin.php?page=be-changelog" class="nav-tab<?php if( $current_screen == 'betheme_page_be-changelog' ) echo ' nav-tab-active'; ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Changelog', 'mfn-opts' ); ?></a>
   97  </h2>

So I tried 
remove_menu_page( 'betheme_page_be-changelog' );
and
  remove_menu_page( 'Changelog'

Comment: but still nothing

Comment: Are these really top-level menus and not the sub-menus from say BeTheme top-level menu? If they really are, try to add you action with a greater priority, say `add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_menu_pages', 99 );`. You need to use page slug with `remove_menu_page()` function, so I think `remove_menu_page( 'betheme' )` should be enough. And if they are sub-menus, you should use [`remove_submenu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_submenu_page/) function in order to remove them.

Comment: No, these are sub-menus. 
I tried adding my page slugs but it seems that I don't know how to add it properly.
From instructions:
[code]
  function remove_submenu_page( $menu_slug, $submenu_slug ) {
      global $submenu;
 
      if ( ! isset( $submenu[ $menu_slug ] ) ) {
          return false;
      }
 
      foreach ( $submenu[ $menu_slug ] as $i => $item ) {
          if ( $submenu_slug == $item[2] ) {
              unset( $submenu[ $menu_slug ][ $i ] );
              return $item;
          }
      }
 
      return false;
  }
[/code]
I try to add my slugs but I  error.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan Shatsky

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and its workig 100%

1st step open this file  `projectName/wp-admin/admin.php`

then

2nd Step  in footer of the page insert this code

`<style> li a[href="admin.php?page=be-websites"] { display: none !important; } </style>`

Enjoy My Solution ...